# Sql server pivot table or inner join for daterange and sum column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join

I have a sql problem and not sure how to go about it because I'm not expert in SQL.

My outcome is:

```
**MONTH | 2011 | 2012**
1   8894108.372544  9200915.88732
2   8987154.877656  8188366.52079
3   8135004.323592  9383008.68889201
4   8374239.052416  9660272.13007201
5   9525066.469164  8578163.904876
6   7475397.368328  8606525.720634
7   8992114.52414401    9365367.617496
8   9358753.61943   11048712.924366
9   8853398.95447799    8499947.810022
10  8577323.223498  9225470.14965
11  9265685.67622799    9226157.80527
12  8887908.50775001    8318114.32842
```

Here is my sql.

```
SELECT MONTH( ts.TransactionDate) as [TransactionDate], 
ISNULL(SUM(CAST([SalePrice] AS FLOAT)), 0) AS "SUM([SalePrice]) 2011", s.[SUM([SalePrice]]) 2012]
FROM  [TABLESALES] ts
INNER JOIN (SELECT MONTH( t.TransactionDate)  as [TransactionDate], 
ISNULL(SUM(CAST([SalePrice] AS FLOAT)), 0) AS "SUM([SalePrice]) 2012" 
FROM  [TABLESALES]  t
WHERE [TransactionDate] BETWEEN '2012-01-01' AND '2012-12-31' GROUP BY MONTH( t.TransactionDate)) s on s.TransactionDate = MONTH( ts.TransactionDate)
WHERE ts.TransactionDate BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2011-12-31'
GROUP BY MONTH(ts.TransactionDate), s.[SUM([SalePrice]]) 2012]
ORDER BY [TransactionDate]
```

The Problem I have is the date range could be "2011" to "2015". 
So I dont want to create inner joins multiple times to do this. Is there a better way and please can I have some code examples. Thanks in advance.

I know I am doing a single join when there is date range of 1 year. "2011 to 2012". But its not great when I have to do 2011-2015 so thats 4 years which means 4 inner joins?

Comment: You are looking for a dynamic pivot like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Answer (score 0):

This query will pivot the data:

```
; With Sales(Y, M, sale) as(
    Select Year(TransactionDate), Month(TransactionDate), SalePrice From TABLESALES
    Where TransactionDate >= '20120101' and TransactionDate< '20150101'
)
Select M, [2012], [2013], [2014]
From Sales
Pivot(
    Sum(Sale)
    For Y In ([2012], [2013], [2014])
) as Piv
```

You only need to update the where clause (start and end years) and add all years in the select and for